# How do I store 2 groups of data Integers and Strings into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I'm trying to make a NPC class that describes an npc. A single npc has an ID and has a name. How do I put a list of names into the names and the ids into the ids.

I seperated the names and ids from a text file. m.group() is the ids and m2.group() is the names. So basically what I don't understand is how to add the groups to the list. I tried using

```
getNPC().npcs.add(m.group());
```

but doesn't work?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadFile {

private String path;

public NPC npc; 

public NPC getNPC() {
    return npc;
}

public ReadFile(String file_path) {
    this.path = file_path;      
}

public String[] openFile() throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

    for (int i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
    }

    textReader.close();
    return textData;        
}

int readLines() throws IOException {

    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String aLine;
    int numberOfLines = 0;

    while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        numberOfLines++;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(aLine);

        int id = m.group().indexOf(m.group().length());


        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[a-z\\sA-Z]+$");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(aLine);
        String name = m2.group();
        while (m.find() && m2.find()) {             
            System.out.println(m.group());
            System.out.println(m2.group());
            getNPC().npcs.add(new NPC(id, name));
      }
    }
    bf.close();
    return numberOfLines;
}   
}
```

This is the class I use to seperate the IDS and names from a text file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadFile {

private String path;

public NPC npc; 

public NPC getNPC() {
    return npc;
}

public ReadFile(String file_path) {
    this.path = file_path;      
}

public String[] openFile() throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

    for (int i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
    }

    textReader.close();
    return textData;        
}

int readLines() throws IOException {

    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    String aLine;
    int numberOfLines = 0;

    while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        numberOfLines++;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(aLine);

        int id = m.group().indexOf(m.group().length());


        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[a-z\\sA-Z]+$");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(aLine);
        String name = m2.group();
        while (m.find() && m2.find()) {             
            System.out.println(m.group());
            System.out.println(m2.group());
            getNPC().npcs.add(new NPC(id, name));
      }
    }
    bf.close();
    return numberOfLines;
}   
}
```

Comment: And where you use getNPC().npcs.add(m.group()); ?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether your problem is using the regular expression to extract the two different values, or how to store them. Your question should only be about *one* of those. I would say that your `NPC` class design is seems pretty specious though, in terms of the `List<String>` you've got. I'd expect a `List<NPC>` in the `readLines` method instead...

Comment: Yeah are you sure that m.group() and m2.group() actually contain the values that you want?  It's possible your "extraction" isn't pulling anything.  Might help to add some example ids/names to ensure your Matcher is working

Comment: Yes m.group() and m2.group() contain exactly what I want. I just updated the post. All I want to do is store the information in m.group() and m2.group. m.group() only contain numbers but I'm not sure how to convert it from a String --> Integer. m2.group() only contains letters. (names) I created a npc class but when I try to create a new npc I can't use m.group() because its a String and not a integer. Sorry I'm really confused my self lol

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have separate arrays of ids and names then you need to have two ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> npcIds;
ArrayList<String> npcNames;
```

Then you should be able to do the .add().

A better solution would probably to have an ArrayList of npcs

```
public ArrayList<NPC> npcs;
```

And then you would add to them like so

```
getNPC().npcs.add(new NPC(Integer.parsInt(m.group()), m2.group()));
```

Like what @jon-skeet suggested

Comment: I get a null pointer.           getNPC().npcs.add(new NPC(Integer.parseInt(m.group()), m2.group())); on this line. Exception in thread "main"

Comment: Could you update your code above?  I think you overwrote the NPC class code.  Sorry for the late response....  There isn't enough context to understand what your null pointer issue is.